# Upgrade M.2 to NVMe

Tags: laptop, ssd, nvme, m2-connector

I am using [lenovo v310-15ikb](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/tr/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-v-series-laptops/v310-15ikb/80t3). I am using [Samsung 860 EVO 500GB SSD, SATA M.2](https://www.amazon.com.tr/gp/product/B078WQVX9B/). However, I want to switch to the higher model NVMe, but I am not sure if my computer is compatible.

What is a way to find out?

Image: https://www.hizliresim.com/qc14i34

[image]

Comment: You might wish to understand your expectations. An NVMe drive is certainly faster but not enough so to justify the cost. I have Lenovo machines with both.

Comment: I see, thank you for your help @John

Answer (score 3):

> What is a way to find out?

In this case, the manufacturer's [compatible parts list](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-v-series-laptops/v310-15ikb/80t3/parts/display/compatible) has quite a few NVMe M.2 SSDs.

(In the list, they're mostly labelled "PCIe", but googling all of them by model number confirms that they're specifically NVMe and not some other proprietary PCIe-based SSD).

Usually, the "User's Manual" / "User Guide" or the "Service Manual" / "Repair Guide" would either directly specificy the requirements and/or show a list of compatible parts (allowing you to look up an official part's parameters and find something that matches).

Comment: I see, thank you for your help

Comment: @Editor If the answer is helpful you should accept it.